# How do remove 'One to Many' relationships in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For simplicity I have two classes;

```
Public Class User
{
int Id { get; set; }
string FirstName { get; set; }
string LastName { get; set; }

public virtual List<Phone> Phones { get; set; } = new();
}

Public Class Phone
{
int Id { get; set; }
string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

1.When I add a new phone DbContext automatically adds a new Phone

```
Phone phone = new() { PhoneNumber = TxtPhone.Text.Trim() };
user.Phones.Add(phone);
```

2.When I update a phone DbContext automatically updates Phone

```
user.Phones.First().PhoneNumber = mTxtPhone.Text.Trim();
```

3.But when i remove a phone from the List of User Phones it doesn't automatically removes the corresponding phone entity from database after calling SaveChanges().

```
user.Phones.RemoveAt(0);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I do have to manually remove it from DbContext.

```
dbContext.Remove(phone);
```

Is there any way to automatically remove the related entity when removing it from the 'One' side.

Comment: I know there is no RemoveAt method in DbSet. I'm removing it from the list of Phones which belongs to user as I'm doing while adding it user.Phones.Add(phone).

Comment: There is no `DbSet.RemoveAt`. The `List.RemoveAt` method removes the phone from the user's phones, it doesn't delete the phone object itself. If the `Phone` represented a smartphone *device*, removing it from a user wouldn't mean the device itself was destroyed. The device could be assigned to another user. Removing the phone from the user should only delete a row from the UserPhones table, not the Phones table

Comment: What you want to do would happen if the `Phone` entity was *owned* by `User` and couldn't exist independently. EF Core [does support owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). Try adding the `[Owned]` attribute to `Phone`.